# Mi animacion CSS y JQUERY No funciona! Se retrasa debido al setTimeout

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, popup, timeout

Estoy apunto de terminar un trabajo, pero surgio un problema y no puedo resolverlo. Les agradeceria mucho que me den una mano.

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente: Deseo que pasando 3 segundos despues de cargar o abrir la pagina aparesca mi Pop-up o Ventana modal, pero no quiero que aparezca bruscamente, sino que sea animado. YA le di las animaciones para que aparezca con una trancision de .3s ease all.

El problema es que el fondo oscuro de atras aparece bruscamente, y el pop up, se demora y no aparece al mismo tiempo que el fondo. Osea se demora e incluso parte de la animacion pareciera que se cortara.

Pienso que tiene que ver con el setTimeout que puse con JQuery, ya que cuando recien aparece la animacion se ve fea y brusca. Pero cuando le doy el boton para cerrar el Pop-up , esta desaparece con una bonita animacion, que es la misma que deseo que tenga cuando aparece pero en reversa.

Ojala me haya dado a entender bien. Aqui les comparto mi codigo. Les agradeceria mucho si pueden ayudarme. Gracias

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function showPopup(){
        $(".pop-up").addClass('show');
        $(".pop-up-wrap").addClass('show');
    }
    
    $("#close").click(function(){
        
        $(".pop-up").removeClass("show");
        $(".pop-up-wrap").removeClass("show");
        
    });
    
    setTimeout(showPopup, 3000);

});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

.texto{
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.texto p, h1{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pop-up {
    background: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.473);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.pop-up-wrap {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 950px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition: .4s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.pop-up-title{
    flex-basis: 0;
    height: 460px;
    flex-grow: 1.5;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('office.jpg');
    background-size: 165%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}

.pop-up-title h2,
.pop-up-title p {
    z-index: 10;
}

.pop-up-title h2{
    font-family: 'Chiller';
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.pop-up-title p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.pop-up-title::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(228, 63, 90, 0.75);
}

.pop-up-title::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: -1
}

.suscription {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 2;
    background: #fff;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.suscription:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: -2;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #1F4068;
}

#close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #1bc59b;
}

.sub-content{
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-content h2{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #1F4068;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sub-content p{
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1bc59b;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#subs-email{
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#subs-send{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    background: #E43F5A;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .25s ease background;
}

#subs-send:hover {
    background: #1bc59b;
}

.pop-up.show{
    visibility: visible;
}

.pop-up-wrap.show{
    transform: scale(1); 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ventana Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd33816f91.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="texto">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up">
        <div class="pop-up-wrap">
            <div class="pop-up-title">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="suscription">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <a href="#" id="close"><i class="far fa-times-circle" ></i></a>
                <div class="sub-content">
                    <h2>SUSCRIBETE</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo electronico" id="subs-email">
                        <button id="subs-send" type="submit">Enviar Suscripcion</button>
                    </form>
                    <div class="pop-up-social-items">
                        <a href="#" title="Youtube"><img src="icons8-play-button.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#" title="Facebook"><img src="icons8-facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#" title="Instagram"><img src="icons8-instagram.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea algo así lo que buscas, únicamente agregue transition, a tus clases de show, por que esos cambios no los tienes con animación, si no que al asignarlos los hace inmediato.
Ya seria que tu juegues con los tiempos de la animación, por ejemplo deje que el fondo espere .1 segundos antes de mostrar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    function showPopup(){
        $(".pop-up").addClass('show');
        $(".pop-up-wrap").addClass('show');
    }
    
    $("#close").click(function(){
        
        $(".pop-up").removeClass("show");
        $(".pop-up-wrap").removeClass("show");
        
    });
   
    setTimeout(showPopup, 3000);

});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

.texto{
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.texto p, h1{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pop-up {
    background: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.473);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.pop-up-wrap {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 950px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition: .4s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.pop-up-title{
    flex-basis: 0;
    height: 460px;
    flex-grow: 1.5;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('office.jpg');
    background-size: 165%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}

.pop-up-title h2,
.pop-up-title p {
    z-index: 10;
}

.pop-up-title h2{
    font-family: 'Chiller';
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.pop-up-title p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.pop-up-title::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(228, 63, 90, 0.75);
}

.pop-up-title::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: -1
}

.suscription {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 2;
    background: #fff;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.suscription:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: -2;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #1F4068;
}

#close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #1bc59b;
}

.sub-content{
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-content h2{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #1F4068;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sub-content p{
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1bc59b;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#subs-email{
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#subs-send{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    background: #E43F5A;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .25s ease background;
}

#subs-send:hover {
    background: #1bc59b;
}

.pop-up.show{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .35s ease 0.1s;
}

.pop-up-wrap.show{
    transform: scale(1); 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .45s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ventana Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cd33816f91.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="texto">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem numquam commodi ducimus architecto quam sapiente atque ipsa rerum aliquid consequatur dolorem voluptatum neque adipisci deserunt facilis esse nesciunt, deleniti distinctio, incidunt temporibus enim tempora ex et? Cumque rerum magnam eos reprehenderit, pariatur itaque quaerat ab quia expedita nemo sapiente. Voluptate.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up">
        <div class="pop-up-wrap">
            <div class="pop-up-title">
                <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="suscription">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <a href="#" id="close"><i class="far fa-times-circle" ></i></a>
                <div class="sub-content">
                    <h2>SUSCRIBETE</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu correo electronico" id="subs-email">
                        <button id="subs-send" type="submit">Enviar Suscripcion</button>
                    </form>
                    <div class="pop-up-social-items">
                        <a href="#" title="Youtube"><img src="icons8-play-button.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#" title="Facebook"><img src="icons8-facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#" title="Instagram"><img src="icons8-instagram.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```